# What does Service: storm has neither charm url or branch specified mean?

Tags: juju

When deploying a bundle using `juju-deployer` it constantly says  *Service: NAME has neither charm url or branch specified*. The charm deploys correctly, but I'm curious about what the message means?

```
"storm-slavecluster":
  charm: "local:trusty/storm"
  num_units: 1
  annotations: 
    "gui-x": "800"
    "gui-y": "800"
```

`$JUJU_REPOSITORY` points to my local repository

Comment: Can you update the question with your version of juju-deployer? and the contents of the env var JUJU_REPOSITORY

Comment: I'm not sure how to get the version of juju-deployer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bundle is referencing a local charm. Denoted by the *local* in `local:trusty/storm`. The message - while not immediately obvious - was correct. There was no branch (deploying from VCS like bazaar), nor was there a charm-store url specified (eg: `charm: cs:trusty/hdp-storm`)

### Working with local charms in a bundle

There's an assumption in the juju tooling that this charm should reside within $JUJU_REPOSITORY - and is a common bash export when working with charms that only reside locally. You can set this with a one-liner in bash

```
export JUJU_REPOSITORY=/path/to/charms
```

in my case, this is set to `$HOME/charms`

and the actual storm charm resides in `$HOME/charms/trusty/storm` (referencing the bundle format above - i do beleive we only have hdp-storm in the charm store)

### Updating the bundle to use store-charms

What might be a better option if you're not working with a locally modified storm charm would be to update the bundle to point at the charm store copy which resides [here](https://jujucharms.com/hdp-storm/trusty/4)

Comment: I'm working with local charms. I've made custom additions to most charms. I might look into officially publishing/merging these to the charm store, but I'll wait with that until they are stable and I have a bit more time.

Comment: Can you give more explanation about deploying from a VCS? Is this an alternative to deploying local charms?